# where in Shopify can the SEO be updated?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

where in Shopify can the SEO be updated?

Comment: Are you referring to what is shown in the documentation [Adding keywords for SEO to your Shopify store](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/promoting-marketing/seo/adding-keywords)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of any product details page (or other resource) is a link to the resource, and in there, you can open up editing and make the SEO whatever you want.

Comment: I found it thank you